# Downloading vector latlong boundary data of India's Telecom circles from OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap, administrative-boundaries, india, telecom

I recently came across a couple of really useful sites for downloading vector latlong boundary data for free

converts entered address into lat/long coordinates (has a batch mode):
http://stevemorse.org/jcal/latlonbatch.html?direction=forward

Tool that lets you enter a lat/long coordinate, and then get vector data for the administrative regions that point is in....has an API
http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/

The source of the data in the last link is OpenStreetMap, and these tools together have been great for getting lat/long boundary data of the districts within India's states.  However, I'm wondering if the same boundary data exists for India's telecom circles, similar to a map of US area codes.

Answer (score 2):

The Telecom circles, or rather Telecom Service Areas (as they are now known) in India are roughly based on the Administrative districts.

You can get the list of Services Areas from here: http://www.dot.gov.in/uas/Amendment%20dated%204%20Jul%2007%20to%20CMTS%20&%20%20UASL.pdf

Based on this you could dissolve the district boundaries to get rough service areas.

You could also have a look at the [coverage maps](http://www.ideacellular.com/wps/wcm/connect/aboutus/idea/idea_network_coverage_maps) provided by Idea, which is one of the larger service providers in India.

Comment: Also Note that the service areas are not equivalent to the Area (STD) codes. Each Service Area will contain several hundred area codes.

Comment: Thanks Devdatta--do you know of anywhere that would have a map of the STD codes?  Or a document listing all the STD codes that are contained in each Telecom Service Area?I assume that

Comment: I am not aware of any such map. You could get the list of STD codes, along with the exchange name here (from the BSNL site): http://218.248.243.16/bsnl-web/stdSearch.seam?cid=2592194 These points could be geocoded to show them on a map. I don't think it there is a polygon service area for these codes.

Comment: Sorry, I prematurely hit "enter"
full comment:
Thanks Devdatta--do you know of anywhere that would have a map of the STD codes?  Or a document listing all the STD codes that are contained in each Telecom Service Area? ANd do STD codes just relate to landline phones, or mobile as well?

I'm assuming that
1.) all providers in India have the same Telecom Service areas, and you can tell which telecom service area a mobile number comes from by looking at the first 5 digits of the number

2.) the remaining 5 digits of the mobile number can be used to identify the STD code

Let me know if I'm wrong!

Comment: @GarrettSimpson: It doesn't work that well. For landline numbers, there will be a STD code and a local number. The STD code can be from 3 to 5 digits, and the local number can be 5-8 digits. Mobile Numbers are 10 digit, where the first 4 numbers  can be used to identify the Service provider, and the rest are given by the company according to their own standards.

Answer (score 1):

OpenStreetMap only contains data that was collected by individuals, or supplied by the authorities as public data. Boundaries and US Area Codes belong to the second part.

I rather doubt if Indian telecom would give away their data for free in the same manner.